# Sverchok Vector Interpolation Example

Tags: vector, sverchok, interpolation

Hey I'm super new to sverchok! So I'm trying to learn how you take two lines and interpolate them into a plane like they do in the example within the sverchok docs (https://sverchok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes/vector/interpolation_mk3.html). However, the views of the node systems aren't entirely present in the pics and I can't seem to replicate the final plane. I can get the sine output, that much is easy enough. If somebody could show me how the second part of the example is done I'll send them a virtual kiss.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]
on this picture there are two nodes with UV parameters